# C# data structure to handle a file

Tags: c#

I have a file which has data in the following format

```
A   B
-----
40  3
50  2
60  1
```

I have to read the file and store it in a data structure that should help me manipulating the data.

If it is C I would go with linked list. What should I possibly use for C#?

Comment: We need more information about how you plan to use this data, it will help us guide you to the best data structure

Comment: I am planning to average all the values in column A that differ by a value less than 0.1...For example, if there are values 400.23 and 400.234 in column A I would want to average these 2 and store as a single value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.  You can see the [MSDN Reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

With a dictionary you can store these as key/value pairs of type int (if that datatype would persist through your collection).  So this would be a `Dictionary<int, int>`.

The `Dictionary<int, int>` would come in handy if you wanted to have these two values have an understood relationship between them.

```
Dictionary<int, int> YourData = new Dictionary<int, int>();
// fill your dictionary with the data from your file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I have a relationship between them and hence I guess I will opt for a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case the Keys are not unique I would go with this approach.

```
IList<Tuple<string, string>> data = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
data.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("60", "1"));
data.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("60", "14"));
```

The values Item1 = A and Item2 = B in regards to getting the data back out of the Tuple.

Answer (score 1):

It strongly depends on what you mean by "manipulating the data" - if you don't need performant deletion of items you can go with a `List<SomeClass>` and define a class `SomeClass` with two members with appropriate names for your data elements.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you want to do. If you want to use it like a map try [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) if you want a simple list try [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

Comment: I am planning to average all the values in column A that differ by a value less than 0.1...For example, if there are values 400.23 and 400.234 in column A I would want to average these 2 and store as a single value

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary, especially if you are using A (the key) to get B (the value). `Dictionary<Key, Value>`